# Query User.SignInNames using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient on a B2C tenant

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to filter users based on SignInNames. I tried to run

```
Client.Users.Where(u => u.SignInNames.Any(x => x.Type == "emailAddress" && x.Value == email)).ExecuteSingleAsync() as User;
```

where `email` is a local account user whose login name is `admin@{mytenant}.onmicrosoft.com`

But I just get

> Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataErrorException: Encountered an internal
>   server error. --->
>   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error
>   occurred while processing this request. --->
>   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException:
>   {"odata.error":{"code":"Service_InternalServerError","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Encountered
>   an internal server error."}}}

Any idea what's wrong?

---

It seems the client doesn't like it if you have multiple operations in your query, running `SignInNames.Any(x => x.Value == email)` works fine.

Comment: Yes, the signInNames query is supported only using the value. It will search all types. The type is primarily for information purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, **it is not possible to filter on anything other than the SignInName value**.

If this is something you'd like to see this you can request it in the [Graph API UserVoice forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/165567-graph-api).